# Hide sql query from packet sniffers

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, packet

I've got a database login on a desktop application made in C#.

To check if the user exists, I do a `WHERE` clause and get the row returned. If row is returned...then user exists.

My problem is pack sniffers can see the strings being returned. They are encrypted and such but some people could use a auto mated response to fool the application into thinking it was right.

Is there a way to hide my DB stuff from packet sniffers?

Comment: Personally, I'd look at using web-services over a secure channel to talk to an application-server. If you don't trust the comms, and this matters, then: don't let the client application anywhere near the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you can do that by using an encrypted connection (SSL certificate based)... for details and some sample configuration/code see:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191192.aspx
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316898/en-us
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2005/11/10/491563.aspx
- https://serverfault.com/questions/351/how-to-enable-encrypted-connections-to-a-sql-server-instance
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx

Comment: In addition to using TLS, you should check for the trusted CA in your client software in order to prevent man in the middle attacks.